# Add new entries to a table view controller at the top of the table with each new entry

Tags: ios, core-data, tableview, nssortdescriptor

I have a working app so far which basically consists of the following:

Using Core Data, I have 1 Table View Controller with an Add Button which modally calls up a new View Controller prompting the user to add text into three fields. When the user clicks save, the entry is added to the table view controller as a subtitle cell with the information filled in. It works well.

What I am confused about and have been looking for answers is the fact that each new entry gets added to the bottom of the cells, so if there enough cells to fill the screen, the new added entry gets added to the bottom. I would really like to get each new entry to the top of the table view cell.

I have implemented the Alphabetical sortDescriptors which also work, but truthfully, I'd want to add new entries to the top of the Table View regardless of starting character.

My FetchRequest currently looks like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Transaction"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"whoBy.name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]; 

self.transactions = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
```

This is the code that adds the entries to the database:

```
NSManagedObject *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[person setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];

[transaction setValue:person forKey:@"whoBy"];
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get your answers in Descending by Coredata fetch request.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"date" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDesc];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];    

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: Does your core data entity have a date or timestamp field? if yes than  use this code to get object in descending order of you added objects in entity and if No than you can add timestamp field.

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for the comment. I do have a timestamp attribute (field) that I can use. What would the code look like to get this to display in order of creation, according to the timestamp? also, how would I put this into sections (not using a NSFetchedResultsController yet).

Comment: hey use above same code just change entity name date with your timestamp field

Comment: Thanks man - followed that but it's not changing the order. My thikning is because I don't have any code anywhere for the "date" attribute to actually do anything? Where would I put this and what exactly would I put? I'm not asking the user for any input on the date, I just want to use the date attribute as the created date - so the date it was created..

Comment: In fact, I would actually like to modify that. I'll create a textfield for the UI so the user can select a date (year, month, etc) and I want that to be the basis of the search. The table view cell does not have to display the date, but i want the entries to be ordered in that way.. and then eventually to use sectins

Answer (score 2):

you can insert new record at place by

```
 [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:YES ];
```

And also you can done it with by updating your array.

```
You can add object to as:

 [yourArray insertObject:object atIndex:0]; //for first row.
```

Then reload table with new array :

```
 [yourTable reloadData]
```

this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you Pradhyuman - that is very helpful. Which method would I add that code to though? Also, in the [yourArray insertObject, would the object be the managedObjectContext or the entry at each row. Sorry just a bit confused with this! A newbie at development!

Comment: you are calling new view controller on the add button click right?

Comment: So for that you are adding view as a subview or you are calling pushViewController method ?

Comment: I'm actually not calling the pushViewController method. The add button was added in the Storyboard and segued (modally) in the storyboard as well, so I have another view controller which represents the modal view controller which adds the data; that's all working and I'm not passing any information in. From the Add Entry View Controller, I'm adding the entires to the coredata Entity and then from this TableView, I'm just loading in the entries

Comment: ok then reload the UItableview in viewWillAppear method and in that get the data from your coreData entities.

Comment: Thanks Pradhyuman, that's absolutely what I'm doing and it's working like a charm here.. but the entries are getting added at the bottom of the table view.. I want to add it at the top using the code you've provided - would that also be in the viewWillAppear method?

Comment: if you are still getting newly added object at the bottom then one thing is that just change the order of your array

Comment: By this code your array will be reorder and you will get your newly added object at first place.First get data in NSMutableArray and reverse the objects of your Array by using below code:

reversedArray = [[theMutableArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

Comment: and don't forget to write [yourtable reloadData]; method

Comment: Thanks - I still could not get that working with the reverseObject, etc. I can't imagine this is too difficult to ensure new entries are added at the top.. I think's just missing some parameter somewhere because I can do the listing in ALphabetical order and not..?

Comment: I have updated the main question to include the code that adds the entries to the database. Perhaps I have to add them in a different order?

Comment: Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this issue out for future reference if anyone is reading this.

In the Add Entry View Controller (the view controller that adds the entries to the database and has a save button method), I did the following:

1) I added a property to the class (@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *dateToday; 
2) In the save method, I did the following:

```
self.dateToday = [NSDate date]; 
[transaction setValue:self.dateToday forKey:@"createdDate"];
// transaction is looking into the Transaction Entity which has an attribute called createdDate of type Date.
```

3) In the TableViewController and with the NSFetchRequest, I did the following:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdDate" ascending:NO]; 
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]; 
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

And so now, when I create a new entry, because Ascending is set to NO, the newly created entry is at the top of the Table View Controller.

Thanks for your guidance @Pradhyuman Chavda

Comment: Nah brother, thank you so much for your help. Really helped me progress!