# Add new entries to a table view controller at the top of the table with each new entry while using core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, tableview

There are two similar questions on stacoverflow, and my one is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354344/add-new-entries-to-a-table-view-controller-at-the-top-of-the-table-with-each-new) but now I'm using Xcode 5 and my code is different. I tried many different ways but they don't work. On the web there aren't solutions.

Using Core Data, I have 1 Table View Controller with an Add Button which modally calls up a new View Controller prompting the user to add text into 1 field. When the user clicks save, the entry is added to the table view controller as a title cell with the information filled in. 
What I am confused about and have been looking for answers is the fact that each new entry gets added to the bottom of the cells, so if there enough cells to fill the screen, the new added entry gets added to the bottom. **I would really like to get each new entry to the top of the table view cell.**

My table view:

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;

}


- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}




- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fechRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OneMoreCoffe"];

    moreCoffe = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fechRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];


    [self.tableView reloadData];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return moreCoffe.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSManagedObject *differentCoffe = [moreCoffe objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.text = [differentCoffe valueForKey:@"type"];





    return cell;
}
```

My view controller:

```
    @implementation DataViewController
@synthesize textFieldType,differentCoffe;

-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;

}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;

    NSManagedObject *newCoffe = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OneMoreCoffe" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newCoffe setValue:textFieldType.text forKey:@"type"];


    [context save:&error];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (differentCoffe) {
        [textFieldType setText:[differentCoffe valueForKey:@"type"]];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind them ALWAYS being in reverse order, you can just show the newest ones at the top always.

Replace this:

```
NSManagedObject *differentCoffe = [moreCoffe objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with this:

```
NSInteger rowCount = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSections:indexPath.section]
NSManagedObject *differentCoffe = [moreCoffe objectAtIndex:(rowCount - 1 - indexPath.row)];
```